# Transform URL to data frame

Tags: r, xml, url

I have a URL to consult CEP (ZIPCODE) in Brazil.

```
URL: viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/xml/
```

Result:

```
<xmlcep>
<cep>01001-000</cep>
<logradouro>Praça da Sé</logradouro>
<complemento>lado ímpar</complemento>
<bairro>Sé</bairro>
<localidade>São Paulo</localidade>
<uf>SP</uf>
<ibge>3550308</ibge>
<gia>1004</gia>
<ddd>11</ddd>
<siafi>7107</siafi>
</xmlcep>
```

How do I turn this URL into a data frame with the respective columns (cep, logradouro, complemento, etc ...)?

Comment: it would be easier to use `rvest::html_text` you get a much cleaner outpu. you may need to use `html_nodes` on your html document first.

Comment: @Mouad_Seridi, would it be possible for you to write the code for me? I have no knowledge for that.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) from the hint @Mouad_Seridi provides. Then come back with a *specific* question regarding your earnest attempt.